# Completion of the classifying stack $BG$ at a point

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, principal-bundles, classifying-spaces

With the classifying stack $BG$ I have come across "the formal completion of $BG$ at point", which is denoted $\widehat{BG}$, for instance on page 7 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.08578.pdf, but I cannot find a reference for the definition.

My questions are:

1. What is the definition of $\widehat{BG}$?
2. Does the definition arise naturally with a morphism $p: \widehat{BG} \to BG$?
3. In the case of yes to 2, is this morphism finite? What is $p_{*}{\mathcal{O}_{\widehat{BG}}}$?

Comment: Look at Gaitsgory-Rozenblyum, Dg Ind-schemes, or Volume II of their book "Study in DAG".

Comment: I cannot find answers to my questions here, did you have something particular in mind with these references?

Comment: As a functor, the completion $\hat{X}_{Y}$ of $X$ along $Y$ sends a ring $A$ to $X(A)\times_{X(A^{red})}Y(A^{red})$. It's often denoted as the relative de Rham stack $(Y/X)_{\mathrm{dR}}$. (In your case $X=BG$, $Y=*$.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm definitely not the right person to answer that, but hopefully [Cunningham's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward_Cunningham#%22Cunningham%27s_Law%22) will do its thing. You might also want to have a look at Pavel's answer to a somewhat related [question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372565/formal-completion-of-a-quotient-stack?rq=1)

My naive understanding is that it should be the formal stack (e.g. in [this sense](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9812034)) controlled by the DG coalgebra $CE(\mathfrak g)$. In other words this is the quotient of a point by the formal group scheme associated with $G$, as it should of course.

A (probably more general) point of view is that it controls de formal derived moduli problem associated with $\mathfrak g$ seen as a DG Lie algebra, in the sense of [Lurie](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/papers/DAG-X.pdf) and [Pridham](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.0344). As far as I understand it means it represents the functor mapping a "small" augmented commutative algebra $A$ (roughly the $E_\infty$ version of a local $k$-algebra with residue field $k$, I guess) to $Hom_{Lie}(D(A), \mathfrak g)$ where $D$ is the Koszul dual Lie algebra functor. Another reference is [this survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.09556) where this particular example is mentioned as a motivation, though not quite worked out in details I suppose.

I'm fairly sure there is always such a map $p$, and at least if $G$ is smooth $p_*$ should be the "rationalization" functor, i.e. the right adjoint of the inclusion
$$
Rep\ G \longrightarrow Rep\ \mathfrak g.$$